JPA criteria query with inline view in FROM clause
Is it possible to create a query selecting from an inner view using the JPA criteria API?
We would like to create the equivalent of this SQL query:
select iv.customer_id, iv. latest_order_date,
  case when exists (
    select 1
    from shipments sh
    where sh.customer_id = iv.customer_id
      and sh.ship_date = sh.latest_order_date
  ) then 1 else 0 end same_day
from (
  select od.customer_id, max(od.order_date) latest_order_date
  from orders od
  group by od.customer_id
  where od.area_id = 317 and od.status = 'new'
) iv

select od.customer_id ... status = 'new' is the inline view.
The reason why we would like to use the criteria API and why a fixed view or @Subselect will not work is that the where condition in the inline view is very dynamic and complex and could be reused from other places. The above example is simplified.
The main thing that we cannot figure out is how to use the inline view as the entity to select from for the main query, indicated with ??? below:
var inlineView = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
var orderRoot = inlineView.from(OrderEntity.class);
orderRoot.groupBy(...);
orderRoot.multiselect(...);
orderRoot.where(...);

var mainQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
var root = query.from( ??? );

var countQuery = mainQuery.subquery(Long.class);
var shipmentRoot = countQuery.from(ShipmentEntity.class);
shipmentRoot.where(...);

root.multiselect(...);

An alternative approach would also be appreciated. But note the challenge that the exists subquery refers the an aggregated result (latest_order_date) of the inline view.

Not the answer you want, but I don't believe Criteria Query can support this. There is no entity for what you are selecting from, so no way to get type safety or properties though for the main query to use. I know other providers like EclipseLink do support this in JPQL, so you could use their native expression api to build a query similar to criteria api - I don't know Hibernate well enough to know if it has the same easily available.
